# "make install" Fails If StdOut and StdErr Not Redirected

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation

I'm building some source in a docker container on Alpine Linux (it's OpenCV 3.4.1, but not sure if that's pertinent). The shell is `/bin/sh`. If I run either of the following, no problems:

```
make install &> /dev/null
```

Or

```
make install || echo "make install failed"
```

But if I just run `make install`, it fails with error code 2. In the latter case, the `OR` condition is never triggered. Any ideas as to why this might be occuring.

EDIT:
This is the output from

```
make install || echo "make install failed"
echo $?


Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "RELEASE"
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/cvconfig.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig/opencv.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVModules.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVModules-release.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig-version.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/valgrind.supp
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/valgrind_3rdparty.supp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/cv.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/cvaux.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/cvaux.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/cvwimage.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/cxcore.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/cxeigen.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/cxmisc.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/highgui.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/ml.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_core.so.3.4.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_core.so.3.4
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib64/libopencv_core.so.3.4.1" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_core.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opencl/ocl_defs.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opencl/opencl_info.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opencl/opencl_svm.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opencl/runtime/autogenerated/opencl_clamdblas.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opencl/runtime/autogenerated/opencl_clamdfft.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opencl/runtime/autogenerated/opencl_core.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opencl/runtime/autogenerated/opencl_core_wrappers.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opencl/runtime/autogenerated/opencl_gl.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opencl/runtime/autogenerated/opencl_gl_wrappers.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opencl/runtime/opencl_clamdblas.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opencl/runtime/opencl_clamdfft.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opencl/runtime/opencl_core.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opencl/runtime/opencl_core_wrappers.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opencl/runtime/opencl_gl.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opencl/runtime/opencl_gl_wrappers.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opencl/runtime/opencl_svm_20.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opencl/runtime/opencl_svm_definitions.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opencl/runtime/opencl_svm_hsa_extension.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/block.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/border_interpolate.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/color.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/common.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/datamov_utils.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/dynamic_smem.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/emulation.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/filters.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/funcattrib.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/functional.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/limits.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/reduce.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/saturate_cast.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/scan.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/simd_functions.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/transform.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/type_traits.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/utility.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/vec_distance.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/vec_math.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/vec_traits.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/warp.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/warp_reduce.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/warp_shuffle.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/detail/color_detail.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/detail/reduce.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/detail/reduce_key_val.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/detail/transform_detail.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/detail/type_traits_detail.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda/detail/vec_distance_detail.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/affine.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/bufferpool.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda.inl.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda_stream_accessor.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda_types.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.inl.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/directx.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/eigen.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/fast_math.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/ippasync.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/matx.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/neon_utils.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/ocl.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/ocl_genbase.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opengl.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/optim.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/ovx.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/persistence.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/ptr.inl.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/saturate.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/softfloat.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/sse_utils.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/traits.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/va_intel.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/version.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/vsx_utils.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/wimage.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core_c.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cv_cpu_dispatch.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cv_cpu_helper.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/hal/hal.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/hal/intrin.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/hal/intrin_cpp.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/hal/intrin_neon.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/hal/intrin_sse.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/hal/intrin_vsx.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/utils/filesystem.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/utils/logger.defines.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/utils/logger.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/utils/trace.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_flann.so.3.4.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_flann.so.3.4
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib64/libopencv_flann.so.3.4.1" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_flann.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/flann.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/flann_base.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/miniflann.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/all_indices.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/allocator.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/any.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/autotuned_index.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/composite_index.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/config.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/defines.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/dist.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/dummy.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/dynamic_bitset.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/general.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/ground_truth.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/hdf5.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/heap.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/hierarchical_clustering_index.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/index_testing.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/kdtree_index.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/kdtree_single_index.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/kmeans_index.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/linear_index.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/logger.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/lsh_index.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/lsh_table.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/matrix.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/nn_index.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/object_factory.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/params.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/random.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/result_set.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/sampling.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/saving.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/simplex_downhill.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/timer.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib64/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4.1" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_imgproc.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/hal/hal.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/hal/interface.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/detail/distortion_model.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_ml.so.3.4.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_ml.so.3.4
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib64/libopencv_ml.so.3.4.1" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_ml.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/ml.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/ml/ml.inl.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_objdetect.so.3.4.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_objdetect.so.3.4
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib64/libopencv_objdetect.so.3.4.1" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_objdetect.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/objdetect.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/objdetect/detection_based_tracker.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/objdetect/objdetect_c.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_photo.so.3.4.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_photo.so.3.4
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib64/libopencv_photo.so.3.4.1" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_photo.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/photo.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/photo/cuda.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/photo/photo.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/photo/photo_c.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_video.so.3.4.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_video.so.3.4
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib64/libopencv_video.so.3.4.1" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_video.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/video.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/video/tracking.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/video/video.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/video/tracking_c.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_dnn.so.3.4.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_dnn.so.3.4
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib64/libopencv_dnn.so.3.4.1" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_dnn.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/dnn.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/dnn/all_layers.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/dnn/dict.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/dnn/dnn.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/dnn/dnn.inl.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/dnn/layer.details.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/dnn/layer.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/dnn/shape_utils.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib64/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.1" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs_c.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_shape.so.3.4.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_shape.so.3.4
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib64/libopencv_shape.so.3.4.1" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_shape.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/shape.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/shape/emdL1.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/shape/hist_cost.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/shape/shape.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/shape/shape_distance.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/shape/shape_transformer.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_videoio.so.3.4.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_videoio.so.3.4
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib64/libopencv_videoio.so.3.4.1" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_videoio.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/videoio.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/videoio/cap_ios.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/videoio/videoio_c.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_highgui.so.3.4.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_highgui.so.3.4
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib64/libopencv_highgui.so.3.4.1" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_highgui.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_superres.so.3.4.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_superres.so.3.4
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib64/libopencv_superres.so.3.4.1" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_superres.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/superres.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/superres/optical_flow.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_features2d.so.3.4.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_features2d.so.3.4
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib64/libopencv_features2d.so.3.4.1" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_features2d.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d/hal/interface.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.4.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.4
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib64/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.4.1" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_calib3d.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/calib3d.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/calib3d/calib3d_c.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_stitching.so.3.4.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_stitching.so.3.4
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib64/libopencv_stitching.so.3.4.1" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_stitching.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/warpers.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/autocalib.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/blenders.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/camera.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/exposure_compensate.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/matchers.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/motion_estimators.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/seam_finders.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/timelapsers.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/util.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/util_inl.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/warpers.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/warpers_inl.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_videostab.so.3.4.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_videostab.so.3.4
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib64/libopencv_videostab.so.3.4.1" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_videostab.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/deblurring.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/fast_marching.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/fast_marching_inl.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/frame_source.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/global_motion.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/inpainting.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/log.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/motion_core.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/motion_stabilizing.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/optical_flow.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/outlier_rejection.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/ring_buffer.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/stabilizer.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/wobble_suppression.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalcatface_extended.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_fullbody.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_licence_plate_rus_16stages.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_lowerbody.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_profileface.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_russian_plate_number.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_smile.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_upperbody.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalcatface.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalface_improved.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_profileface.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_silverware.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/opencv_traincascade
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/opencv_traincascade" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/opencv_createsamples
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/opencv_createsamples" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/opencv_annotation
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/opencv_annotation" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/opencv_visualisation
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/opencv_visualisation" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/opencv_interactive-calibration
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/opencv_interactive-calibration" to "/usr/local/lib64"
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/opencv_version
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/opencv_version" to "/usr/local/lib64"
0
```

Comment: Is there any error message that goes along with that?

Comment: @Barmar, not that gets printed to the console, the `RUN` section in the dockerfile just ends with `returned a non-zero code: 2`.

Comment: Try `echo $?` after the make install.  This will print the exit code.

Comment: Can you redirect to a real file and look at its contents?

Comment: We can't help until you can get the output from the `make install` command and see why it failed, and post it here.  There's nothing in make itself which would fail or not fail based on whether stdout/stderr is a terminal versus a file.

Comment: @MadScientist, but in the example of `make install || echo "FAILED"`, "FAILED" is never written to stdout (and thus make install doesn't return a non-zero error code) and the command does not appear to fail. I'm running another build now and will add all of the output from the command.

Comment: It sounds like the message is coming from one of the commands in the makefile, but make itself isn't failing.

Comment: Well, make is clearly not exiting with error code 2, since you're printing it and it's 0.  Why makes you think it's failing with error code 2?  You still haven't shown us any error message or failure output.

Comment: @MadScientist, maybe I wasn't being clear. When the docker build `RUN` step fails at `make install` there are no error messages produced via stdout or stderr from the command. Docker reports that the `RUN` step failed with a non-zero error code: 2. See my comment to Barmar above.